# Android : Download and Share html file issue

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application I want to download and share one html file. so I tried the following code:

```
Button download = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downloadbtn);
        download.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String file_url= "/* http url*/";
                 new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);

            }
        });

}


class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread
         * Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
                String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/sridhar.html";
                // Output stream to write file
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
       }

        /**
         * After completing background task
         * Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

            goShare();
        }

    }
    public void goShare(){
         String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/sridhar.html";
            // setting downloaded into image view
         Log.e("Downloaded path","Path is "+filePath);
         Uri fileuri = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath(filePath));


          //  MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            //String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension("html");
            //File file = new File(imagePath);
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           // shareIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),mimeType);
           // shareIntent.setFlags(shareIntent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileuri);
            shareIntent.setType("text/html");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share"));
    }
```

The problem is , I can able to download my html file but i cant share that ...
i.e I can able to bring the share context menu and selecting gmail, the file is not accepted by gmail app and it forces the gmail app close.

And also the progress bar is not working...

Please provide me the best way to share the downloaded file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution :

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
 shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
 shareIntent.setType("text/html");
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share"));
```